# Tensorflow Object Detection model 320x320 and 640x640 difference

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am working on a project using TensorFlow API to perform object detection implement in Android app. In [TF2 Dectection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), there are same model with different feed in image size, such as `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320` and `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640`. Some said that resize images by using `fixed_shape_resizer` and `keep_aspect_ratio_resizer` in config file.

I look through the `pipeline.config` file of `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320` and `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640`, the only difference is that

SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 320
    width: 320
  }
}
```

SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 640
    width: 640
  }
}
```

Does it mean that `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320` and `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640` are actually the same if I change the image_resizer parameter?

My training images and detection are 2560x1440 (image size of Android mobile phone). Is that if I change the `pipeline.config` of either `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320` or `SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640` to

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 2560
    width: 1440
  }
}
```

, then no resize will be done on image when feeding in the model? Thanks.